# How to populate a webform variable

Tags: vb.net, webforms, webbrowser-control

I'm attempting to use VB.Net WebBorwser to populate and submit a webform. I'm using webbrowser because I don't know much javascript or c#. I'm open to other ideas of course.

I'm able to populate the form fields easily enough:

```
m_oWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("line1").SetAttribute("value", "Flat 12")
```

but this isn't enough to trigger the page to set the require variables. I've also tried:

```
m_oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("line1").InvokeMember("change")
```

and

```
m_oWebBrowser.Navigate("javascript: PreviousAddress().Address().Line1='Flat 19';")
```

The input field looks like this:

```
<input id="previousAddressLine1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" name="previousAddressLine1" tabindex="12" data-bind="value: PreviousAddress().Address().Line1" type="text">
```

Any help would be great.

-Ben

Comment: When you are filling in the form manually, is there a popup suggestion box or a auto-filling element?

Comment: Hi @Pure, there's no popup or drop down or the like.

Comment: Does anything happen if you use the id "previousAddressLine1" and set the value of that element?

Comment: @Pure Ah, I gave the wrong code in my original post. I should have typed: `<input name="line1" id="line1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 valid" tabindex="16" data-bind="value: CurrentAddress().Address().Line1" type="text">`

Comment: Look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh870013(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi @MrGadget, I don't have the method. [screenshot of my methods](http://screencast.com/t/e4glWV3P4)

Comment: Did you try `m_oWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("line1").value = "Flat 12"` ?

Comment: @MrGadget Value is not a method I have either. See screenshot. I noticed you're asking me about documented methods which I don't seem to have. I'm usng VS2013 and ave tried with 4.5.1 and 4.6.2 frameworks.  http://screencast.com/t/NL6cpICBtHSt